Fallback handler contract and Safe modules
I deployed a Safe, using the relay-kit com the SafeSDK. In the Safe UI, in the Modules section, I see that there is a section for Safe modules and another one for fallback handlers.
I deployed this Safe following the guides from the Safe docs, and surprisingly, I see that the fallback handler set is unofficial.
How is that possible?


Thanks!
